# Android: How to align button to the bottom and above the keyboard when it is up?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/task_title"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Trying to align a few buttons at the bottom of the screen. However when the keyboard pops up, I want the buttons to move up to above the keyboard. How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml just add this attribute:
**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

```
<activity 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:name="com.example.stackoverflow.SimpleActivity5" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate the activity in the manifest. See [the manifest documentation on attribute android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft), you need to specify `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` so that when the keyboard is displayed, the viewport for your activity is resized to the area above the keyboard and hey presto! buttons re-appear.