# Display a view on top of keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view

I am making a application in which i want a linear layout to be displayed on top of the keyboard.When the user closes the keyboard that linear layout should also be gone.
I want it something like this

[image]

Layout what i want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_Img1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_Img2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/cam" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llEditOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_font"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/save_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_font"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/cam" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_size"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_font"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/share_1" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCamOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_Camera"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/save_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Camera"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/cam" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_Share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_Camera"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/share_1" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is from ios phone but can we implement this functionality in android???

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Where is you code ?

Comment: Nah i didnt find anything how to do it.Please can you guide me???

Comment: aadd your layout code in question

Comment: I have updated my post ,please do have a look

Comment: Is your issue solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer which helped you most.

Comment: This Question has already been answered in [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837236/android-how-to-align-button-to-the-bottom-and-above-the-keyboard-when-it-is-up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the keyboard is shown the whole layout is squashed because there is less space available. All you have to do is align the `LinearLayout` to the bottom of the screen and it will be displayed directly above the keyboard. You could for example use a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ... // The content of your layout goes here            

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        // This LinearLayout will be aligned to the 
        // bottom of the screen and displayed above your keyboard

    </LinearLayout>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `ScrollView` is just there to make your layout scrollable when the keyboard opens and there isn't enough room anymore to display all of it at once. The `LinearLayout` at the bottom will be positioned independently at the bottom of the screen and overlap anything else.

The `ScrollView` also has a padding which is equal to the size of the footer `View` and has `clipToPadding` set to `false`. This means the `ScrollView` can use paddings to display content. You need this or otherwise the bottom part of your layout would be hidden behind the `LinearLayout` at the bottom. You can make the `LinearLayout` a little transparent for a nice effect when scrolling.

Comment: But when i keyboard is hidden i dont wanna display tat layout

Comment: @user3917131 So just hide it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have programatically added a textview.But when i open keyboard with that method that textview is going under the keyboard

Comment: What do you mean? Did you use the exact layout from above? If you added the `View` programmatically are you sure you set all relevant properties correctly?

Comment: I just tested my solution and it is working perfectly.

Comment: And to make the footer visible only when the keyboard is showing is going to be almost impossible. You can come pretty close by setting its initial visibility to `View.GONE` and then set a `OnFocusChangedListener` on the `EditTexts` and if one of them has focus you can set the visibility of the footer to `View.VISIBLE`. But this will never work perfectly. It is impossible to listen to keyboard open or close events. I think the only way you can reliably do what you want to do is to write a custom keyboard.

Comment: this solution's not working for me . can any one post answer?