# How can I add custom view to my custom keyboard in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, ime

How can I add custom view as in image, in my android keyboard?
I need row to have different background color, label and buttons.

[image: Please see the image here]

Comment: see this example you get idea how to achieve this http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android/10465/

Answer (score 2):

In your InputMethodService, you define a function called onCreateInputView. Have it return whatever view you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your view as a footer view. So whenever android keyboard visible your view will looks on top of keyboard.

Comment: Have you try your solution ? keyboard will show above all view in layout. your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: It is not app specific , it's actually IME.

Comment: Yes I tried it in one of my application. when keyboard visible then view goes up; Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787955/display-a-view-on-top-of-keyboard