# How to get left and right arrow keys on android keyboard?

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm trying to get left and right arrow keys on android keyboard. Here is the example from IOS keyboard how it should look like.

[image]

This is my look so far. I only miss these arrows.

[image]

Here is the example of my XML code for edit text.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_view_login_title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_login_username_relative_layout_bottom_margin">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_username"
        style="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view_username">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_username"
            style="@style/MyEditTextTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_username_title"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_login_username_edit_text_size"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/ime_action_label_title"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_username"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_login_icon_image_view_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_login_icon_image_view_size"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_login_icon_image_view_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_username_light_blue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Android keyboard don't have that button like IOS. you can define your custom view.

Comment: @Akash Can you give me example of how to make custom view for keyboard ?

Comment: Reefer this link [How to Draw view on top of keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060579/how-to-draw-view-on-top-of-soft-keyboard-like-whatsapp?answertab=votes#tab-top) [Display view on top of keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787955/display-a-view-on-top-of-keyboard)

Comment: @BhargavParmar Thank you